# Typescript: How do I import and add typings for a nested file in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript

installed with:

```
npm install highcharts
typings install highcharts/highstock --ambient
```

index.ts:

```
import * as Highstock from 'highcharts/highstock'
new Highstock() // Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "outFile": "./dist/index.js",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "ty.d.ts",
    "src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for anyone that finds this question in the future, i needed to wrap the highcharts typings like so:

```
declare module 'highcharts/highstock' {
  // typings go here
}
```

i assume there's some way to re-export the community typings from inside this declared module, but for now i'm manually adding typings as i go.

Answer (score 1):

> new Highstock() // Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

TypeScript definitions for *JavaScript* libraries are best effort (i.e. might not be up to date). That definition file (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/highcharts/highstock.d.ts) does not support such usage. If that is a usage that *should* be supported feel free to create a Github Pull Request

Comment: what's the right way to build a definition? i tried the following but it doesn't make a difference: https://gist.github.com/bcherny/f11903a6a7e28c7ecb0c